# How can I remove extra space under contents using BS3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I was working with the official BS3 example http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-static-top/ Which somehow leaves extra spaces below the content (Please click the link for see in action). How can I make it auto adjusted by the contents?
Please consider me as learner.

Comment: "Which somehow leaves extra spaces" how can anybody know what you mean here..

Comment: @Hardy please click the link.

Comment: We are not a Mind Reader. We can give Solution only when your question is clear; However I am guessing you might want to remove the padding on class `.jumbotron`?

Comment: @KheemaPandey I understand. *.jumbotron* class has a bottom padding of 50px

Comment: then what else you want to solve?

Comment: I found the solution from @Hardy's answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/24668994/907044 . It was for the *min-height:2000px* that did the problem. Thanks for helping me :)

Comment: Well, someone catch the point; but you should be more careful in future when asking a Question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The body has: `min-height: 2000px;` that's why there is extra space..

Comment: It worked! Thanks. Sorry for being silly as I dig up the BS3 file but  missed the additional one.

Comment: NP. Try using Firebug in Firefox to inspect elements.. that's way it's easy to see these kind of things :)